# Create a shell script that reads folders in a specific folder and outputs their size and name to a file

Tags: shell, unix

Would like to create a shell script that will read the contents of a folder that contains many folders on a server- it should output a list of these folders with their size and date modified if possible.

Comment: The size of a directory is often 4096.  By "size", do you mean the number of entries in the directory?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it recursively (it's not clear to me from the question whether or not you do), you can do:

```
$ find /path/to/dir -type d -exec stat -c '%n: %s: %y' {} \;
```

(If you have a find which supports the feature, you can replace '\;' with '+')

Note that the %s gives the size of the directory, which is not the number of files in the directory, nor is it the disk usage of the files in the directory.

Comment: with CGNU find, you dont need to call out to stat: `find path -type d -printf "%f\t%s\t%TY-%Tm-%Td\n"`

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l /path/to/folder | grep ^d`

Comment: if i did this in vi, as a script- how would i put this output to a file, like a txt file. the full vi script would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this find command to list sub-directories and their size (since stat command doesn't run same way on mac and Linux):

```
#!/bin/bash
find /your/base/dir -type d -exec du -k {} \; > sizes.txt
```

Comment: if i did this in vi, as a script- how would i put this output to a file, like a txt file. the full vi script would be helpful.

Comment: @James: I edited the answer above to capture output as well. You can copy/paste my answer into a file called checkSizes.sh and run it using `bash checkSizes.sh` or else first `chmod +x checkSizes.sh` then run it as: `./checkSizes.sh`